# Cannot execute binary file after xbuild compilation on server

Tags: c#, linux, mono, wine, xbuild

I have written a web application with my own server in C# using Monodevelop. On my computer I compile it and run it without any problems. However, I tried to deploy it on a server, and after successful compilation of .sln file with xbuild and running .exe file I get:

"Cannot execute binary file."

Obviousle .exe has +x flag. Here is result of uname:

> uname -a
>
> Linux xxxxx 3.10.19-2 #1 SMP Thu Nov 14 10:42:59 CET 2013 x86_64 Intel(R)_Xeon(R)*CPU****_*__***X7460*_@_2.66GHz PLD Linux

And here is result of file

> file Server.exe
>
> Server.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows

So I run a 32-bit app on 64-bit machine, which should be ok. "For MS Windows" is quite disturbing, but on my computer file command gives the same output. Here is result of uname on my computer:

> uname -a
>
> Linux xxxxx 3.13.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 7 22:30:23 CET 2014 i686 GNU/Linux

However, .exe file is not a Unix script. I can run it under Wine on my computer, but Wine is not available on the server. What can I do to run my app on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Linux distribution does not ship with Mono, so you have to,

1. Install Mono according to the distribution manuals. Sounds like you are using a Debian derivative, then you should run `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`.
2. Run your binary by calling `mono your.exe`.